# Json list not 'flattening' properly

Tags: json, r, list

I have the below list in a column of a data frame.

As you can see, the variables change through the items. The column `affilications` is not always present.

I have been trying to `flatten` the list to a data frame or to a `list of 3`, but I am geeting a single columg with all elements of every column.

Is there a way I can tell `R` that each element has 3 columns and that the first one is not always present and to fill it with let's say `null`.

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
        affiliations author_id     author_name
1 Punjabi University  780E3459     munish puri
2 Punjabi University  48D92C79 rajesh dhaliwal
3 Punjabi University  7D9BD37C       r s singh

[[3]]
  author_id         author_name
1  7FF872BC barbara eileen ryan

[[4]]
  author_id      author_name
1  0299B8E9 fraser j harbutt

[[5]]
  author_id        author_name
1  7DAB7B72 richard m freeland

[[6]]
NULL
```

This is what I'm getting when I try and flatten it.

```
              authors
1  Punjabi University
2  Punjabi University
3  Punjabi University
4            780E3459
5            48D92C79
6            7D9BD37C
7         munish puri
8     rajesh dhaliwal
9           r s singh
10           7FF872BC
```

But what I really need would be:

```
[[1]] NULL

[[2]]affiliations author_id     author_name
1 Punjabi University  780E3459     munish puri
2 Punjabi University  48D92C79 rajesh dhaliwal
3 Punjabi University  7D9BD37C       r s singh

[[3]] NULL   author_id         author_name
1     NULL   7FF872BC barbara eileen ryan
```

Answer (score 1):

I i understand you correctly you have data as follows:

```
require(tidyverse)

list(
  NULL,
  tibble(a=c(2, 2), b=c(2, 2), c=c(2, 2)),
  tibble(b=3, c=3)
)
```

So:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2     2
2     2     2     2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      b     c
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3
```

Using `bind_rows` results in:

```
bind_rows(list(
  NULL,
  tibble(a=c(2, 2), b=c(2, 2), c=c(2, 2)),
  tibble(b=3, c=3)
))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2     2
2     2     2     2
3    NA     3     3
```

Comment: So that means I would need to know the dimensions of all items? This is a sanple of the dataset. I have couple of millions of rows.

Comment: No. Just try it Out.

Comment: Sorry, I get: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`